# When can users flag questions and answers, and how are those flags reviewed?

Tags: discussion, flags

Can anybody give me a brief introduction to the Stack Overflow flag system?

- How much reputation does a user need to flag a question or answer?
- How do flags get reviewed?
- Who can review flagged questions and answers?
- If the flagged post is valid, but numerous users have flagged it, what action(s) do moderators take?
- How many flags are needed for a stupid answer or question to be deleted?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/150789

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions are answered on the following two [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) sub-sections:

1. [Flag Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts)

> What happens when I flag something Offensive or Spam?
>
> The offensive and spam flags are designed to automatically eliminate
>   truly offensive posts through the collaboration of the community.
>
> 3 flags -- post is banished from the front page. 6 flags -- post is
>   locked, deleted, and the owner loses 100 reputation. Users with the
>   Moderator Tools privilege can see how many offensive flags a post has
>   accrued, and may opt to flag it themselves.
>
> What happens when I flag something Requires Moderator Attention?
>
> You'll be required to enter a comment briefly explaining what the
>   problem is. After that, these moderator flags go in a special high
>   priority queue visible to all moderators. We take moderator flags
>   quite seriously; rest assured that they are all followed up on!

2. [Moderator Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)

> When should I act on vote-to-close and vote-to-delete flags?
>
> ...
>
> These flags will appear on the list of flagged posts in your moderator
>   tools. You will not be able to see who cast each flag, however.
>   ...